# Pin app terminated abnormally due to signal 6

Tags: linux, mpi, instrumentation, hpc, intel-pin

I am trying to use Pin tool and loopprof to instruments my cluster using MPI, but pin terminated  abnormally due to signal 6 with this error:

```
A: Source/pin/pin/image.cpp: IMG_Type: 374: The img passed to IMG_Type() is stale
####################################################
## STACK TRACE
####################################################
addr2line -C -f -e "loopprof" 0x2b5b678a02c9 0x2b5b678a10b6                                                                                                
??
??:0
??
??:0
??
??:0
??
??:0
??
??:0
??
??:0
??
??:0
Pin 2.14
Copyright (c) 2003-2015, Intel Corporation. All rights reserved.
@CHARM-VERSION: $Rev: 71293 $
@CHARM-BUILDER: BUILDER
@CHARM-COMPILER: gcc 4.4.7
@CHARM-TARGET: ia32e
@CHARM-CFLAGS:  __OPTIMIZE__=1  __NO_INLINE__=__NO_INLINE__
Pin app terminated abnormally due to signal 6.
```

Can anybody help me to fix this error??

Comment: Consider sharing your tool's code.

Comment: Attach a debugger to your tool and look at the call stack. Look at the last line of code you modified before getting this error. Tell us what pin tool you are using (your own tool or someone else's)...

Comment: And reply when others try to help...